# Current timestamp. Incorrect time

Tags: org-mode, time-date

Linux, Emacs 27.2

I want in org file to insert current data and time. Now in my machine is **02 June 10:56 AM**.

So I use command

```
C-u C-c .
```

Here result:
[image]

Why time is incorrect?

Comment: Probably nothing to do with org-mode.  Do `(format-time-string "%c")` and `(current-time-zone)` return the values you expect?

Comment: @phils  After set time zone, the problem is gone. (set-time-zone-rule "GMT-3")

Comment: I think there's still an issue if the system time zone that Emacs is seeing by default isn't correct.  I wouldn't expect that users should need to call `set-time-zone-rule`, but if you do then the docstring indicates that you should probably prefer `(setenv "TZ" "GMT-3")`.

Comment: And perhaps better than that would be to set `TZ` in the environment that Emacs inherits in the first place, if the default behaviour is wrong, as it might be more than just Emacs defaulting to the wrong zone.  A bit of reading suggests that this is getting into system-specific territory though, so you'll need to follow up on the details yourself.